# django admin list_filter does not display (None) for choice field

Tags: django, django-admin

My model contains a choice field that is nullable:

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
```

The filter in my ModelAdmin:

```
list_filter = ['status']
```

does not display (None) as an option, even though the table for the model contains NULL values for that field.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post might be of use: [Filtering Django Admin by Null/Is Not Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691890/filtering-django-admin-by-null-is-not-null)

When using choices I'd recommend setting a default value which is in the choices list or tuple. This ensures the [get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method works for all values too.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: My solution was to specify the FieldListFilter type in the ModelAdmin, i.e.: list_filter = [('status', AllValuesFieldListFilter)]. I dug into the admin/filter.py source code to figure this out, so that's one up for AndrewS for leading me to a solution. Since the doc contains the warning "The FieldListFilter API is considered internal and might be changed.", I am keeping this question as unanswered.

Comment: and sorry Andrew, I am not allowed to vote you up (not enough reputation points!) :(